# Sky Texture not rendered properly

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I'm using the default World Sky texture settings for my scene. There's a dark bluish rectangle positioned at the middle of the sky texture when rendered as compared to its appearance in the 3D viewport. [image]

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: That is likely not caused by the sky itself, there may be objects, modifiers, or clipping at work here. Impossible to tell without knowing more about your scene

Comment: I'm quite unsure if it has something to do with the rendering distance of the camera. Its end clipping is at 1500. I'll try creating another scene and see if it gets better

Comment: It would also help if you uploaded your file so others can improve the scenes settings.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the End Clipping of the camera (Max viewing distance) was the one causing the issue. **I down-scaled all the objects in my scene and set the clipping distance of my camera from 1500 down to 100 and that fixed the problem.** [image]

Do not set your render distance past 200 as it will most likely give you clipping issues.