# Ocean Flyover issue

Tags: rendering, animation, scene

I'm at the middle of a project wherein I need to animate an establishing shot of an ocean with the camera moving forward fast enough to give a dramatic effect. I'm using a default sky texture as background for this scene.

[image]

My Problem is:

1. Once my camera reaches a point where it views the horizon of the ocean, the camera cannot reach the certain amount of viewing distance needed to render the whole ocean, and when I increase the end clipping of the camera, I get this issue instead.

[image]

Compared to this one wherein it has no clipping issue but the render distance is insufficient.

[image]

There's a thread (https://blenderartists.org/t/vfx-shot-pacific-ocean-flyover/560817) in blenderartists.org forum wherein someone was able to execute an ocean flyover properly and it is exactly how I want the scene to turn out.

[image]

**How do I increase the render distance without having any clipping issues?**

Here's the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_xGYEJZIcd2KqXwRYlvGWVf_3bmOHYoP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sky Texture not rendered properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109872/sky-texture-not-rendered-properly)

Comment: I'm the one who created that post. The reason why I can't afford to down-scale the ocean is because it will not look big enough for the camera, well at least as far as I know.

Comment: Then modifiy your previous question and remove the answered tag, the thread will get bumped to the top automatically. Add additional information about what you want to achieve there. This seems to be the same problem, your previous solution does simply not satisfy the further progress.

Comment: Hmmm okay I'll try to upload the blender file here instead.